# Unable to connect MySQL server at localhost 3306 using netbeans 11.3

Tags: java, mysql, maven, netbeans-11

In the `Maven` project. When I first set up `XAMPP` and `MySQL` work very well. But inside `NetBeans` I can't connect to the `MySQL` and can't create a connect to the **mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.zip** or **mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar**.
`driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"` and `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"`
[image]
[image]

When I going to add new connection to `MySQL` it display error message,

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added the jar file in build path?

Comment: yes @HarmandeepSinghKalsi

Comment: `driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"` is obsolete. User `driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Netbeans automatically taks driver as com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver I can't change it to com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Answer (score 0):

"The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one-time zone"
This is a common error in MySQL to fix this error.
1)Create a new connection to MySQL
2)Connect JDBC driver to using mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar
3)In JDBC URL add server time zone as follows make sure your database name is mysql otherwise change the database name to your database name.
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?serverTimezone=UTC
**NB:-**If you want you can add server time zone as a connection property
set property as serverTimezone and value as UTC.

If this didn't work use MariaDb driver to connect MySQL
1)Create a new connection
2)Add mariadb-java-client-2.6.0 to the connection
3)In JDBC URL add as follows and you don't want to worry about server time zone when you use MariaDB
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mysql

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running on windows but the solution for me involved customizing the mysql driver.
On the netbeans services tab open the drivers folder right-click the mysql connector/driver and then cutomize. Locate your driver on your system and add it to the class then click ok. Worked for me on ubuntu